# Grep: show only 2nd line above

Tags: linux, bash, script, grep

Let's say I have a text file with the content:

```
foo
bar
whatever

something I don't know
bar2
whatever
```

And, as an output from doing `grep whatever myfile.txt` (and/or `sed` and/or `awk`), I would like to have:

```
foo
something I don't know
```

I've tried using option `-B 2` but that outputs both `foo` and `bar`.
Cannot do `... | grep -v bar` as there are a lot of different records.

Comment: There's not enough context here to know exactly what you are trying to get. If you'd grep'd for 'foo' you'd have got foo and foo2, so why wouldn't that work?

Comment: I obviously don't know what's there, this is just an example. Anyways, question edited so it's easier to understand.

Comment: Do you always want the line 2 lines above the result, or the last line after a blank line?

Is there blocks of 4 or more results, if so, what result would you want?

Comment: I always want the 2nd line above the matching pattern, they are as well in blocks of 3, so I'd want the very first line of every block.

Comment: -1 Your question is unclear because you clearly don't just want the 2nd line above. Maybe you want the 2nd line above and the first line after the coming new line.  But your question doesn't state that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So here's my solution as I couldn't find any way of doing it:

As I was being returned with blocks of content, say:

```
foo
bar
whatever
--
foo2
bar2
whatever
--
```

and so on, I used grep's separator and got the very next line like so and then removed them:

```
grep -B2 whatever myfile.txt | grep -v whatever | grep -A 1 -E '\-\-' | grep -v  -E '\-\-'
```

And that just outputs:

```
foo
foo2
```

Comment: -1 more utter lack of clarity.. So you write the output at the bottom.. what's that block at the top then which you say is returned.. Is that not "output"?  Is that first lump you wrote in your answer the result of a grep, or is it new test data. Can't you quote directly from the cmd prompt. And you make no effort to explain the logic of your solution either.

Answer (score 0):

Not grep, but should work:

> awk '/grep_string/ {print a} {a=b;b=$0}' file